# Attempt to get length of null array when encode pdf file

Tags: java

This is  my code

```
public static String convetFiletoString(File f)
{
    byte[] bA = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
        int bR;

        while ((bR = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            bos.write(b, 0, bR);
        }

        bA = bos.toByteArray();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(bA, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

I got an exception like this = Attempt to get length of null array
, I checked Uri it working.

Comment: PLease add the complete Stacktrace not ony a summary

Comment: Unrelated, but you should be using a try-with-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `return Base64.encodeToString(bA, Base64.DEFAULT);` is outside the `try...catch` block. This means that if an exception occurs before `bA = bos.toByteArray();` then `bA` will still be `null`. The most likely solution is to put the `return` inside the `try...catch`.

Comment: it work, but i got another exception: file not found. i think get path from my uri not reply the real path. my uri like this 'content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ABla.pdf'

Comment: @Ferdy Please post a new question with the current version of your code and a full stack trace.